# How can I add multiple cloud functions to a single load balancer in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud, load-balancing

I am trying to add all of my cloud functions to a single load balancer in GCP.

When I try to add multiple backend servers to a load balancer, the GCP interface does not allow it. I can only select option BE server. Any ideas on how to acheive this so I do not need to create a load balancer for each function.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.